How can I deselect the pressed button in NavigationDrawer?
I am using Kivy 2.0.1 and I created a topAppBar with the "menu" icon, this opens a NavigationDrawer with different buttons that when clicked could change to different windows depending on the button, the problem is when I change the window and then I go back to the first window, the window I clicked on first is still selected and that's confusing because someone thinks it's in the window that the button is selected and that is false.
enter image description here
For example, in the image you can see that "Secondary sheet" is selected, but in reality I am on "main page", only it remains selected even though the windows are changed. This is my kv file:
<MainScreen>: 
    MDScreen:
        MDNavigationLayout:
            MDScreenManager:
                MDScreen:
                    name: "main_screen"

                    # Barra superior en la parte superior
                    MDTopAppBar:
                        id: top_app_bar
                        type: "small"
                        pos_hint: {"top": 1}

                        MDTopAppBarLeadingButtonContainer:
                            MDActionTopAppBarButton:
                                icon: "menu"
                                on_release: nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")

                        MDTopAppBarTitle:
                            text: "Página Principal"

            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer
                drawer_type: "modal"
                
                MDNavigationDrawerMenu:

                    MDNavigationDrawerHeader:
                        orientation: "vertical"

                        MDLabel:
                            text: "Menu"
                            font_style: "Title"
                            role: "medium"
                            adaptive_height: True

                    MDNavigationDrawerDivider:
                    
                    MDNavigationDrawerItem:
                        on_release: app.root.current = 'hoja1'
                        
                        MDNavigationDrawerItemLeadingIcon:
                            icon: "home"
                        MDNavigationDrawerItemText:
                            text: "Página principal"

                    MDNavigationDrawerItem:
                        on_release: app.root.current = 'hoja2'
                        
                        MDNavigationDrawerItemText:
                            text: "Hoja secundaria"

                    MDNavigationDrawerItem:
                        on_release: app.root.current = 'hoja3'
                        
                        MDNavigationDrawerItemText:
                            text: "Hoja secundaria 2"

this is my main.py
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer,MDNavigationLayout, MDNavigationDrawerItem, MDNavigationDrawerItemTrailingText
from kivymd.uix.appbar import MDActionTopAppBarButton, MDFabBottomAppBarButton, MDTopAppBar

Window.size =(400,700)
Builder.load_file('kvs/hoja1.kv')
Builder.load_file('kvs/hoja2.kv')
Builder.load_file('kvs/hoja3.kv')

class WindowManager(MDScreenManager):
    pass

class MainScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class SecondaryScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs) :
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def build(self):
        self.wm = WindowManager()
        screens = [
            MainScreen(name = 'hoja1'),
            SecondaryScreen(name = 'hoja2'),
            SecondaryScreen2(name = 'hoja3'),
        ]
        for screen in screens:
            self.wm.add_widget(screen)
        return self.wm

if __name__== "__main__":
    MainApp().run()

Note: "Hoja 2" and "Hoja 3" kv files are the same structure as "Hoja 1"
I hope someone can help me so that it doesn't stay selected when I change and return from the pages.
Thank you.
